# GLPK java java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, glpk

The dynamic link library for GLPK for Java could not be loaded.
Consider using

```
java -Djava.library.path=
The current value of system property java.library.path is:
\\MILP\lib\glpk-4.55\w64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
\\MILP\lib\glpk-4.55\w64\glpk_4_55_java.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.gnu.glpk.GLPKJNI.<clinit>(GLPKJNI.java:24)
    at org.gnu.glpk.GLPK.glp_version(GLPK.java:2259)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:7)
```

1. I have added the correct JAR file
2. I have given the correct native path for the library

Still the problem persists,

One doubt I have is that the \MILP\lib\glpk-4.55\w64\glpk_4_55_java.dll file is flawed. I checked it using dependencyWalker there it shows some warnings

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
```

Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I also faced same issue. I copied glpk_4_55.dll and glpk_4_55_java.dll to C:\Windows\System32 and Everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the C:\Program Files\GLPK\glpk-4.55\w64 folder to your PATH environment variable

or

copy the glpk_4_55.dll and glpk_4_55_java.dll to C:\Windows\System32  as suggested by Pradeepb